# ImportError: No module named copy_reg pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to unpickle an object stored as a blob in a MySQL database. I've manually generated and stored the pickled object in the database, but when I try to unpickle the object, I get the following rather cryptic exception:

ImportError: No module named copy_reg

Any ideas as to why this happens?

**Method of Reproduction**

Note: Must do step 1 on a Windows PC and steps 3 and 4 on a Linux PC.

1) On a Windows PC:

```
file = open("test.txt", "w")
thing = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
cPickle.dump(thing, file)
```

2) Manually insert contents of text.txt into blob field of MySQL database running on linux

3) In Python running on a linux machine, fetch the contents of column from MySQL

4) Assuming that you put the contents of the blob column into a variable called data, try this:

```
cPickle.loads(rawString)
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: This was with Python 2.4

Comment: What would code add in this situation?

Comment: @Stephen Edmonds: Since there's no code, I was forced to assume what code you were using.  Sadly, the code I assumed worked perfectly, so I couldn't reproduce your problem.  If I had your code, instead of mine, I might have been able to help.

Comment: @ S.Lott: I've now added code snippets, but as you can see, they don't really help much. The main reason why the issue is hard to reproduce is that you need to pickle the object on Windows, save it to a file and then try and unpickle it on Linux.

Comment: @Stephen Edmonds: I note that none of the Windows-Linux stuff in the original question.  It turns out that providing the code also included useful, interesting facts.

Comment: The extra weirdness with this is, that even if 'copy_reg' exists inside the sys.modules you get the cryptic ImportError: no module named copy_reg.

Comment: This issue is even more frustrating to deal with when git changes the line endings on windows machines

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems this might be caused by my method of exporting the pickled object.

[This bug report](http://www.archivum.info/python-bugs-list@python.org/2007-04/msg00222.html) seens to suggest that my issue can be resolved by exporting to a file writen in binary mode. I'm going to give this a go now and see if this solves my issue.

UPDATE: This works. The solution is to make sure you export your pickled object to a file open in binary mode, even if you are using the default protocol 0 (commonly referred to as being "text")

Correct code based on orignal example in question:

```
file = open("test.txt", 'wb')
thing = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
cPickle.dump(thing, file)
```

Comment: Again, what exactly would code show? How would it be of benifit to this answer?

Comment: If just want to mention that `No module named copy_reg pickle` can be also any other module name like in my case. This might be confusing during debugging.

Answer (score 16):

Also, simply running dos2unix (under linux) over the (windows-created) pickle file solved the problem for me. (Haven't tried the open mode 'wb' thing.)
Dan

Comment: This shoiuld be an asnwer

Answer (score 3):

just an interactive python session to show that you don't need any particular code to have this problem:

do something like this on a windows machine

```
Python 2.4.1 (#65, Mar 30 2005, 09:13:57) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle, re
>>> empty_string = re.compile("^$")
>>> pickle.dump([empty_string,1,1.23,'abc'], file('m:/mario/test-b.dump','wb'))
>>> pickle.dump([empty_string,1,1.23,'abc'], file('m:/mario/test-t.dump','wt'))
>>>
```

and then try to retrieve the data from a linux box

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.load(file('/home/mario/.gvfs/transfer on 192.168.0.4/mario/test-b.dump'))
/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py:1124: DeprecationWarning: The sre module is deprecated, please import re.
  __import__(module)
[<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xb7d42420>, 1, 1.23, 'abc']
>>> pickle.load(file('/home/mario/.gvfs/transfer on 192.168.0.4/mario/test-t.dump'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named sre
>>>
```

the error message can be even more confusing if you are just pickling base types.  this is what I get with the list `[12, 1.2, '']`:

```
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer use

```
dos2unix originalPickle.file outputPickle.file
```

OR use the tr command like below (removes carriage returns and ctrl-z)

```
  tr -d '\15\32' < originalPickle.file > outputPickle.file
```

OR use `awk` (`gawk` or `nawk` if its old versions)

```
  awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' originalPickle.file > outputPickle.file
```

OR if you can recreate a pickle file in linux, use that.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing going on here is that you don't seem to have closed the file after dumping the pickle to it.   the error reported here can sometimes be caused (whether on a windows machine or otherwise) by not closing the file.

Answer (score 1):

my issue：

```
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    subsection_struct_model = pickle.load(f)
```

when i get the model.pkl from windows run this code in my mac,this issue is comming

solve:

```
dos2unix model.pkl
```

is ok!

Answer (score 1):

This happen because in Windows, new line symbol is stored as "\r\n", and that in Linux is "\n",so what you should do is to read the pickle file line by line, replace "\r\n" with "\n", and write it back to the file.

**Unlike the dos2unix approach will skip binary file, this also works well for binary pickle file.**

Code is simple:

```
#run this code on Linux platform

DIR="your/dir/to/file"

pickle.load(open(DIR,"rb"))
# ImportError: No module named copy_reg pickle

a=open(DIR,"rb").readlines() #read pickle file line by line

a=map(lambda x:x.replace("\r\n","\n"),a) # replace \r\n with \n

with open(DIR,"wb") as j: #write back to file in binary mode
    for i in a:
        j.write(i)         
pickle.load(open(DIR,"rb")) 
#Now it works well
```

Also, you can use normal write mode, just change "wb" to "w" and "rb" to "e".

Comment: Straightforward answer. Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, because of git changing the 
line endings on windows.

I solved the problem by adding a `.gitattributes` file to my repo:

```
# Pickle files (for testing) should always have UNIX line endings. 
*.pkl text eol=lf
```

See also https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

The pickle load may not be looking in the same location as your python script. Sometimes the directory changes on the basis of your application. Just before you load the pickle, print a os.getcwd() to work out a solution.