# Python: No module named copy_reg

Tags: python, database

I've been making a simple database in Python and I began working on it on a windows pc and have now adapted onto using a laptop with linux in it.

The script I've made and have been using has been working perfectly on my windows pc,but I have recieved errors upon opening it in Linux.

I have installed all the necessary modules for my script on both my computers.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/Desktop/Pi/Database.py", line 169, in <module>
    Students_list = pickle.load(fin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named copy_reg
>>> "
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/556295/373151

Answer (score 3):

this is import error means it can not able to find path of copy_reg. you should give path for copy_reg. and don't forget to add **init**.py file in each directory.if you have still issue then write down you code here..

Thanks

Comment: In which directory i am supposed to add init.py and and where can i give the path to copy_reg?