# Pickle figures from matplotlib: 2

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pickle, figure

Following [Pickle figures from matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649603/pickle-figures-from-matplotlib), I am trying to load a figure from a pickle. I am using the same code with the modifications that are suggested in the responses. 
Saving script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pl

# Plot simple sinus function
fig_handle = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
# plt.show()

# Save figure handle to disk
pl.dump(fig_handle,file('sinus.pickle','wb'))
```

Loading script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pl
import numpy as np

# Load figure from disk and display
fig_handle = pl.load(open('sinus.pickle', 'rb'))
fig_handle.show()
```

The saving script produces a file  named "sinus.pickle" but the loading file does not show the anticipated figure. Any suggestions?

Python 2.7.13
matplotlib 2.0.0
numpy 1.12.1

p.s. following a suggestion replaced fig_handle.show() with pat.show() which produced an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
   site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 109, 
   in_set_device_scale
   self.figure.dpi = self.figure.dpi / self._device_scale * value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", 
   line  416, in _set_dpi
   self.callbacks.process('dpi_changed', self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", 
   line  546, in process
   if s in self.callbacks:
   AttributeError: 'CallbackRegistry' object has no attribute 'callbacks'
```

Comment: you are right. I have edited my question

Comment: `fig.show()` would only work in interactive mode. Else you need to call `plt.show()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried to make this modification to the code and faced the following error:

Comment: This might be a problem with the MacOS backend. You may try using a different backend, like "TkAgg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution included modification of 
    fig_handle.show()
to 
    plt.show()
and modification of the backend to "TkAgg", based to an advice given by  ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 0):

What you call your "loading script" doesn't make any sense.

From the very link that you provided in your question, loading the picked figure is as simple as:

```
# Load figure from disk and display
fig_handle2 = pl.load(open('sinus.pickle','rb'))
fig_handle2.show()
```

Comment: The "loading script" works fine in itself, so maybe it's a bit hard to say that it does not make sense, just calling it "loading script" is a bit confusing, right?

Comment: True, maybe that was harsh. The part that does not make sense is to willingly call a Figure instance `ax`