# Is it possible to save the window obtained with plt.show() in a navigable format and not as a simple image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to save the navigable window showing the graph with plt.show()?

Comment: When you mean by "navigable" that it should include the buttons (pan, zoom etc) from the navigation toolbar then the answer is no - these are part of the backend, not the image.

Comment: I just followed the idea to save the figure object with `pickle`, and even found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649603/pickle-figures-from-matplotlib, but it doesn't work for me at least, sorry: `Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure()`

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503869/attributeerror-while-trying-to-load-the-pickled-matplotlib-figure/54579616#54579616

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `plt.savefig("graph.jpg")` to save your figures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=None, metadata=None)
```

for more info:
[matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)